# mySQL Query date where select

Tags: mysql, date

i have table like this:

```
+----+--------------------+-------------------+
| id | name               | date_departure    |
+----+--------------------+-------------------+
|  1 | karyawan karantina | 2017-02-10        |
|  2 | karyawan berangkat | 2015-11-24        |
|  3 | asdf               | 2013-04-18        |
+----+--------------------+-------------------+
```

i want to show data where date_departure o later than 1 year of departure .
so the expected data like this :

```
+----+--------------------+-------------------+
| id | nama               | tanggal_berangkat |
+----+--------------------+-------------------+
|  2 | karyawan berangkat | 2015-11-24        |
+----+--------------------+-------------------+
```

please help me... thanks before... sorry for my english. Im indonesian...

Comment: so 2017 hasn't happened yet.  2013 has and 2015 is current year.  So you're wanting to see anything with a date of departure within 1 year of current date?  If so look at date_add and between functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're after flights within 1 year of current date..

This seems to be a pretty straight forward SQL statement... what's the problem?

[Manual with relevant functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
SELECT ID, Name, Date_Departure
FROM tablename
WHERE date_Departure between date_Add(now(),Interval -1 year) and
 date_Add(now(),Interval +1 year)
```

or if you truely mean between now and 1 year from now you don't need the date add on the first segment of the between.

```
SELECT ID, Name, Date_Departure
FROM tablename
WHERE date_Departure between now and
 date_Add(now(),Interval 1 year)
```